# Problem with PWM pins on Arduino uno

Tags: pwm, arduino-motor-shield

I am working on an Arduino Uno Project of a car with two motors. The motor driver board is an L9110 H-Bridge. Here is how everything is connected:

[image: Schematic]

And here is the code I am trying to run:

```c
//Define all the pins for the motors
#define motorPinA1 3  //A pin right motor
#define motorPinB1 5  //B pin right motor
#define motorPinA2 6 //A pin left motor
#define motorPinB2 9 //B pin left motor


//Movement functions
void stopCar();
void frwrd(int motorSpdRight, int motorSpdLeft);
void back(int motorSpdRight, int motorSpdLeft);


//Global Variables
int motorSpeedRight = 0;  //The speed of the right motor
int motorSpeedLeft = 0;   //The speed of the left motor

void setup() {
  //Movement
  pinMode(motorPinA1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorPinB1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorPinA2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorPinB2, OUTPUT);

  //Serial Monitor for debugging
  Serial.begin(9600);

  motorSpeedLeft = 100;
  motorSpeedRight = 100;

  frwrd(100, 100);
  delay(2000);
  stopCar();
  delay(1000);

  back(100, 100);
  delay(2000);
  stopCar();
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {

  Serial.print("Forward");
  Serial.print("\n");

  frwrd(motorSpeedRight, motorSpeedLeft);
  delay(2000);
  stopCar();
  delay(1000);

  back(motorSpeedRight, motorSpeedLeft);
  delay(2000);
  stopCar();
  delay(1000);

}

// functions we need to make the code run
void stopCar(){
    Serial.print("Stoping Car\n");
    // Put motor 1 in halt
    analogWrite(motorPinA1, 0);
    analogWrite(motorPinB1, 0);

    // Put motor 2 in halt
    analogWrite(motorPinA2, 0);
    analogWrite(motorPinB2, 0);
}

// For the farward direction A pins will be high
void frwrd(int motorSpdRight, int motorSpdLeft){
    // Put motor 1 (Right) in forward motion with speed = motor_spd
    analogWrite(motorPinA1, motorSpdRight);
    analogWrite(motorPinB1, 0);

    // Put motor 2 (Left) in forward motion with speed = motor_spd
    analogWrite(motorPinA2, motorSpdLeft);
    analogWrite(motorPinB2, 0);

    /*
    // Put motor 1 (Right) in forward motion
    digitalWrite(motorPinA1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorPinB1, LOW);

    // Put motor 2 (Left) in forward motion
    digitalWrite(motorPinA2, HIGH);
    analogWrite(motorPinB2, LOW);
    */
}

// For the backward direction B pins will be high
void back(int motorSpdRight, int motorSpdLeft){
    // Put motor 1 (Right) in backward motion with speed = motor_spd
    analogWrite(motorPinA1, 0);
    analogWrite(motorPinB1, motorSpdRight);

    // Put motor 2 (Left) in backward motion with speed = motor_spd
    analogWrite(motorPinA2, 0);
    analogWrite(motorPinB2, motorSpdLeft);

    /*
    // Put motor 1 (Right) in backward motion
    digitalWrite(motorPinA1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorPinB1, HIGH);

    // Put motor 2 (Left) in backward motion
    digitalWrite(motorPinA2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorPinB2, HIGH);
    */
}
```

Pins 3, 5, 6 and 9 are PWM so I can `alalogWrite()` to them and control the speed of the motors. Code uploads fine but although both motors move forward normally motor 1 (on pins 3, 5) doesn't move backward. The strange thing is that if I use `digitalWrite` (the commented code in the two functions) instead everything works normally but the motors move in full speed so it's not usable for my project. I have tested all the pins in other projects and everything worked fine so I know my board is not faulty.

I have also taken some measurements with a multimeter while the code was running. In the forward motion, both pairs of pins measured 1.95V. In the backward motion, the problematic pins measured 0V.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: start debugging by testing the motor driver ... swap wires on the arduino output pins .... not related to the question, but the pin naming in your sketch is somewhat confusing `motorPinA1` is not as clear as `motor1fwd` or `motorLeftFwd`

Comment: The l9110 has 4 input pins named IA1, IB1, IA2, IB2 so that's why I named them that way. As for the swaps, I have tried a lot of combinations but I did not get consistent results so I was a bit confused

Comment: @Juraj This is not exactly my problem. I don't have reverse movement at all on one motor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try different pins than 5 and 6, because those PWM generators share the timer with `delay()`, which I'd interpret as: You use `analogWrite()` to set the timer to fire every n microseconds to toggle your PWM signal  -- and then you call `delay(1000)`, which sets that same timer to fire in one second to continue the program.

Pins 10 and 11 do use a different timer, so try these.

Reference: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/

> "The PWM outputs generated on pins 5 and 6 will have
>   higher-than-expected duty cycles. This is because of interactions with
>   the millis() and delay() functions, which share the same internal
>   timer used to generate those PWM outputs."

Comment: I will try that and I will get back on you.

Comment: `delay()` doesn't interfere with PWM the way you imagine. Actually, _using_ `delay()` does not interfere with PWM _at all_. The fact that the timer is shared does have some consequences on the timer settings. On pins 5 and 6, the PWM frequency is higher (976.6 Hz instead of 490.2), and the duty cycle slightly larger: (n+1)/256 instead of n/255, where n is the value you `analogWrite()`.

Comment: Your solution seems to have solved the problem for now so I will accept your answer. Although when I try to run the same code as part of a more complicated project I get the previous results. I will try to debug and if I don't get results I will open another question. Thanks for your time